# python 2 read file name contain ♣ in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, unicode, path

I am using python2 to manage some folder and files on windows.

My Windows encoding is `GBK`, `path.decode('gbk')` is fine for most files.

## Example code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals, absolute_import

from pathlib2 import Path
from six import text_type, binary_type

def text(string, encodings=['utf8', 'gbk']):
    if isinstance(string, text_type):
        return string
    elif isinstance(string, binary_type):
        for encoding in encodings:
            try:
                return string.decode(encoding)
            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                pass
        else:
            raise Exception('Can not decode with %s' % encodings)

    else:
        return text_type(string)


root = Path('./data')
for x in root.iterdir():
    if x.is_dir():
        print text(x.parts[1])
```

## But not work for some filename:

Such as contain `♣` ,  at this line `if x.is_dir()` would throw error

```
  File "e:\Workspace\PixivUtil2\StorageManager.py", line 50, in __init__
    self.refresh()
  File "e:\Workspace\PixivUtil2\StorageManager.py", line 90, in refresh
    if x.is_dir():
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pathlib2.py", line 1463, in is_dir
    return S_ISDIR(self.stat().st_mode)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pathlib2.py", line 1257, in stat
    return self._accessor.stat(self)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pathlib2.py", line 481, in wrapped
    return strfunc(str(pathobj), *args)
WindowsError: [Error 123] : 'data\\464063 - ?3'
```

comment out the dir check, directly write file would get

```
[Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: u'data\\464063 - ?3\\11111111.txt'
```

I know `♣` can not display on windows cmd, because `GBK` doesn't contain it, that's why it shows as `?` .

But how to make python handle this problem correctly ? I want to read the folder name and create file under it.

Comment: You need to upgrade to Python 3 or not rely on Path and do the work manually.

Comment: @Burhan Khalid  The lib I depend is python2 only , hard to convert to python3, that's why I stress python 2 in title .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problems is with `pathlib2` on Python 2.x at least:

```
>>> from pathlib2 import Path
>>> root = Path(u'.')
>>> for f in root.iterdir():
...   print f
...
???.txt
```

Normally, if you use Unicode paths, you get Unicode filenames:

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('*.txt')
['???.txt']
>>> glob.glob(u'*.txt')
[u'\u9a6c\u514b\u2663.txt']  # u'马克♣.txt'
```

I suggest using `os.listdir()`:

```
>>> import os
>>> for f in os.listdir(u'.'):
...  print repr(f)  # to avoid UnicodeEncodeError...
...
u'\u9a6c\u514b\u2663.txt'
>>>
```

Really, switch to Python 3.6:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.listdir('.')
['马克♣.txt']
```

Comment: You are right,  only `pathlib` has such problem. I though it just package `os` and `os.path` to high level , so didn't try `os.listdir`.